# How can I use a column's values for DATEADD()'s datepart parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Dummy 
(
    Latest_Appointment_Date date, 
    Interval varchar(255), 
    Increment int
); 

INSERT INTO #Dummy (Latest_Appointment_Date, Interval, Increment) 
VALUES ('2023-11-10', 'week', 2), 
       ('2023-11-23', 'month', 1);
```

Where the interval and increment columns denote how much I want to increment the date by (using `DATEADD`, for example). I can't figure out how to use the column values as the parameters of my `DATEADD`.

When I do

```
SELECT 
    *, DATEADD(Interval, Increment, Latest_Appointment_Date) 
FROM #Dummy
```

I get the error

> 'Interval' is not a recognized dateadd option

Any insight would be great. Thank you. I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: have you tried dynamic sql_?

Comment: `Interval  varchar(255)` is excessive for what-is-essentially just an `enum` column needing a handful of values... also, you should ensure all your columns are `NOT NULL` otherwise they're `NULL` by default, which is a mistake...

Comment: @Dai, maybe it's for internationalization support

Comment: @siggemannen `DATEADD`'s keywords aren't localized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[T-SQL's `DATEADD` is not a "real" function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), it's actually a language-feature (like a statement or control-structure) and the first parameter (`datepart`) accepts keyword arguments, not value arguments, so you cannot parameterize it using a `@variable` nor column expression...

...instead, you'll need to use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT
    t.*,

    CASE t.Interval
        WHEN 'year'  THEN DATEADD( year , t.Increment, t.Latest_Appointment_Date )
        WHEN 'month' THEN DATEADD( month, t.Increment, t.Latest_Appointment_Date )
        WHEN 'day'   THEN DATEADD( day  , t.Increment, t.Latest_Appointment_Date )
        WHEN 'week'  THEN DATEADD( week , t.Increment, t.Latest_Appointment_Date )
        WHEN 'hour'  THEN DATEADD( hour , t.Increment, t.Latest_Appointment_Date )
        /* etc for the other defined keywords, tedious, huh? */
    END AS NextDate
FROM
    #Dummy AS t
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is basically what Dai said. Here's an inline table valued function you can use to abstract away that logic so you can reuse it elsewhere if you need (I copied all the various possible inputs to the proc from the [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) documentation)

```
create or alter function dbo.DynamicDateAdd
(
    @Interval varchar(30),
    @Increment int,
    @Date date
)
returns table
as
return
select
    NewDate = case
        when @Interval in ('year', 'yy', 'yyyy') then dateadd(year, @Increment, @Date)
        when @Interval in ('quarter', 'qq', 'q') then dateadd(quarter, @Increment, @Date)
        when @Interval in ('month', 'mm', 'm') then dateadd(month, @Increment, @Date)
        when @Interval in ('dayofyear', 'dy', 'y') then dateadd(dayofyear, @Increment, @Date)
        when @Interval in ('day', 'dd', 'd') then dateadd(day, @Increment, @Date)
        when @Interval in ('week', 'wk', 'ww') then dateadd(week, @Increment, @Date)
        when @Interval in ('weekday', 'dw', 'w') then dateadd(weekday, @Increment, @Date)
        when @Interval in ('hour','hh') then dateadd(hour, @Increment, @Date)
        when @Interval in ('minute','mi', 'n') then dateadd(minute, @Increment, @Date)
        when @Interval in ('second', 'ss', 's') then dateadd(second, @Increment, @Date)
        when @Interval in ('millisecond', 'ms') then dateadd(millisecond, @Increment, @Date)
        when @Interval in ('microsecond', 'mcs') then dateadd(microsecond, @Increment, @Date)
        when @Interval in ('nanosecond', 'ns') then dateadd(nanosecond, @Increment, @Date)
        else null
    end

go
```

**Example Usage**

```
declare @Now date = getdate()

;with inputs (Interval, Increment) as
(
    select 'day', checksum(newid()) % 3 union all
    select 'week', checksum(newid()) % 3 union all
    select 'month', checksum(newid()) % 3 union all
    select 'year', checksum(newid()) % 3 union all
    select 'not-an-input', checksum(newid()) % 3 
)
select
    Now = @Now,
    a.Increment,
    a.Interval,
    b.NewDate
from inputs a
cross apply dbo.DynamicDateAdd(interval, Increment, @Now) b
```

Comment: Your UDF would be better-defined as a scalar UDF `WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON` for performance, and `@interval varchar(11)` instead of `varchar(30)` - and `@date` should be `datetime2(7)` (or `sql_variant` if you're brave enough) to avoid truncation.

Comment: @Dai iTVFs are just as performant as UDFs with inlining (essentially the latter is transformed into the former). OP had `date` so not worth widening it for no reason. `sql_variant` should certainly be avoided. The `varchar` length is unlikely to make a significant difference except a slightly larger memory estimation, it only makes a real difference on the actual table storage.

Comment: @Charlieface _"ITVFs are just as performant as UDFs with inlining"_ - I'm not confident this is always true - especially since the changes to UDFs since 2019 - got a citation?

Comment: @Dai Take a read of the research https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/froid/publications/ and you will see that is essentially what's going on under the hood to transform it to an iTVF, with an extra not-insignificant compilation cost, and a LONG list of exceptions where it doesn't work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver16#requirements